# Entityframework, control creation of a new object

Tags: entity-framework, controls, createobject

I am trying to update an object of class **Transaction**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> GroupId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> PaidForUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual User PaidByUser { get; set; }
```

The element PaidForUsers is a collection of the **User** object

```
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
```

Here Id is auto generated and UserId is to be supplied by code.

What I am trying to do is, whenever I create a new transaction, I should create a new User only if the user is not present already in the database.

I am currently using DbContext.Transactions.Add(*new transaction*). This obviously creates a new user in the database everytime I create a new transaction.

The solution that I have adopted currently is to use a custom stored procedure only for the User Entity which tries to do the same thing. But I get the following error in that also

*The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.*

Here is the stored procedure -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
    (@UserId bigint )
AS
declare @val bigint
declare @countza int

SELECT @val= Id  FROM dbo.Users1 where UserId = @UserId
set @countza = @@Rowcount

    if @countza = 0
    begin
    insert into dbo.Users1 (UserId) values (@UserId)
    select [Id] from [dbo].[Users1] 
            where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = scope_identity() 

    end
    else
    begin
        SELECT  'Id' = @val
    end
```

Can some one tell what is the best way to do this? Is creating a stored procedure the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the right way - under "normal" circumstances - is to use LINQ:

(I'm assuming that `UserId` must be unique, but is not the primary key (which is `Id`))

```
var transaction = context.Transactions.Create();
var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
if (user != null)
    transaction.PaidForUsers.Add(user);
else
    transaction.PaidForUsers.Add(new User { UserId = userId });
context.Transactions.Add(transaction);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If your operation is very performance critical, then the right way might be a Stored Procedure.